# how to use ng-template in angular correct for below error

Tags: angular

```
   <p-column field="boreNumber"  [hidden]="selBoreID" header="Bore ID" 
   [sortable]="true" [filter]="false" filterMatchMode="contains" 
   filterPlaceholder="Search bore number">
<ng-template  let-col let-bore="rowData" pTemplate="body">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link" (click)="showDetails(site.siteId)">{{bore[col.field]}}</button>                
                  </ng-template>
              </p-column>

 <p-column  field="site.siteNumber" header="Site Number" [filter]="false" filterMatchMode="contains" [sortable]="true" filterPlaceholder="Search site number">
<ng-template let-col let-bore="rowData" pTemplate="body">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" (click)="showDetails(site.siteId)">{{bore[col.field]}}</button> </ng-template>
</p-column>
```

In my second column ng-template is not working my second column is an object again

Comment: Post the code were you set the data, please

Comment: <p-dataTable [value]="searchBores" reorderableColumns="true" sortMode="multiple" rowGroupMode="subheader" [groupField]="groupByCol"
                [expandableRowGroups]="(grpBy && !(groupByCol ==='') )" [sortableRowGroup]="false" [rows]="10" [paginator]="true"
                [pageLinks]="5">
                <p-header class="text-left">
                  <div>
                    <p-menubar [model]="items" styleClass=""></p-menubar>
                  </div>
                </p-header>
                <p-footer>{{totalRecord}} Bore(s) are found</p-footer>

Comment: I meant the class code

Comment: boreId?: String,
    status?: String,
    boreNumber?: String,
    createdBy?: UserDetails,
    createdDate?: Date,
    modifiedBy?: UserDetails,
    modifiedDate?: Date,
    site?: Site;  here Site is an object with more properties